# Codeigniter + Angular Js: How to keep flashdata?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, validation

**This is the situation:**

I am making a simple app using Codeigniter + Angular Js.

I made a client side validation with Angular and server side validation with Codeigniter.
The both are working fine, except one thing, quite important: i am not able to display the flashdata messages from server side validation.

Probably redirect to the login page it takes more than one server request and flashdata is then lost.

**This is what i have done:**

In the codeigniter controller:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('errors', 'Username/password combination not correct');
$this->session->keep_flashdata('errors');
redirect('#/login');
```

In the view:

```
<?php 
      echo validation_errors(); 
      if ($this->session->flashdata('errors')) 
      { 
         echo '<p>' . $this->session->flashdata('errors') . '</p>';
      }
?>
```

Reading in StackOverflow and Google have thought that the solution would be using:

$this->session->keep_flashdata

but is not working in my case.

**This is the question:**

How can i keep flashdata for more than one server request?

I cannot load a view because i am inside an angular js partial, so i must redirect. But i have to be able to keep at any cost the flashdata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding `$this->session->keep_flashdata('errors');` in the same function, add this in the constructor of the controller. This will keep the flashdata for another server request, allowing it to be used afterwards.